# How i could to reload a imageView with a constant chaged setAlpha?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a effect similar to disolvense at the inverse changing the alpha parameter with a for, but the image doesn't change beetwen 0 and 1 only change when the alpha become 1.
PD. in my code the image is with setAlpha = 0
Here is the code of the method:

```
-(void)splash:(UIImageView *)img{    

    for (double i=0.0; i<=1.0; i=i+0.1) {
        for (int x=0;x<=10000;x++){
            for (int h=0;h<=10000;h++){

            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%g",i);
        [img setAlpha:i];
        [img reloadInputViews];
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you doing inside the `x` and `h` (the two inner) loops?

Comment: its like a manual sleep() like 'C' lenguaje

Comment: The `sleep` function can be used in Objective-C. Remember, Objective-C is a superset of C. But please note that using `sleep` is NOT the correct solution. I'm just pointing out that the `sleep` function is available in iOS apps.

Comment: i use a sleep() in objective c but the simulator was to speed to see the console NSLog values, thats the reason i use that 2 for()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a basic view animation to fade in the image view:

```
- (void)splash:(UIImageView *)img {
    img.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        img.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}
```

Set the duration to whatever desired result you want (in seconds).

Comment: OOOOOOOH!!! thats work tank you by hte way after animations: its a block right? its necesary to use in the implement?

Comment: Yes, the `animations` parameter is a block. It is necessary for this method. Do you not wish to use blocks? If not, why?

Comment: because my knowledge of blocks is very basic, and i dont know the truely power of that tool, and make the same thing without block, could let me understand the use of the block

Comment: The use of blocks here is very simple. The code between the curly braces (`{ }`) on the `animations` parameter is the block of code that is executed for the animation. For example, you could also change the view's frame in addition to the `alpha` property.

Comment: mmmmmmmmm maybe the question could be why the programmer use a block like a parameter and dont implements a simple method with "normal" parameters

Comment: Because a "normal" parameter only allows you to pass a value. A block allows you to pass more code. The whole point here is that the block of code is a parameter and the block of code is executed by the implementation of the `animateWithDuration:animations:` method. The block of code can contain any number of lines of code. It's not just for animating a view's `alpha` property.

Comment: so the implement of animateWithDuration:animations: method is prepare for receive any line of code for the block?, beacuse the programmer could put the programation for the block in the method

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use UIView animation (as suggested above and you probably should use that way), then you can try a recursive loop like this:

```
- (void)performSplashAlpha:(UIImageView *)img
{
    img.alpha += 0.1;

    if(img.alpha < 1)
        [self performSelector:@selector(performSplashAlpha:) withObject:img afterDelay:0.1]; //Or whatever timing you want in between alphas
}
```

Comment: The alpha can't be more than 1.

Comment: I think you meant alpha <= 1

Comment: Ah ok there we go. Thanks!

Comment: that method was very interesting to, the use of recursivity its interesting very much thanxs, but maddy answer first with a interesting method that use a block, anyway thank you very much

Comment: @YoMariano This isn't recursion. It also gives you a non-smooth animation. Unless that is the effect you want, this is not the best solution.